# Sage 300 (accpac) SDATA: Create Order

Tags: accpac

I'm attempting to use the Sage SDATA Rest Service to create an order.  So far I can't seem to find what components make up an order in oeorders.  Here's the Endpoint that I'm trying to hit:

[POST] http://{company}/SDataServlet/sdata/sageERP/accpac/{org}/oeorders/

So, how do I figure out what elements are required in my payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was going wrong.  You have to use POST when shipping a new order, not PUT.  The most minimal payload seems to be the following:

```
<entry xmlns:sdata="http://schemas.sage.com/sdata/2008/1" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <sdata:payload>
        <oeorder xmlns="http://schemas.sage.com/sageERP">
            <TERMS></TERMS>
            <CUSTOMER></CUSTOMER>
        </oeorder>
    </sdata:payload>
</entry>
```